# select lightning input checkbox by name in aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightninginput, dom

I want to select the lightning input checbox by name from my Aura component controller. How can I do that?

```
<lightning:input type="checkbox" label="{!parentBenefit.Name}" name="{!parentBenefit.Id}" onchange="{!c.callCheckboxMethod}" />
```

I am able to get the name of the checkbox using the below code.

```
var parent = event.getSource().get("v.id");
```

Now using the above value I am trying to set the lightning input type checkbox.

```
document.getElementsByName(parent)[0].selected = true;
document.getElementsByName(parent)[0].checked = true;
```

But not able to make it work.

Comment: You'll need a different approach. What you're trying to do isn't possible in Aura.

Comment: So how can I get another checkbox to be checked based on some checkbox is checked or not